# NP complete or NP hard, in a equivalences problems?

Tags: graph, complexity-theory, graph-theory, np-complete, np

I ran into a question.

> Finding of all cycle in a graph is NP-Complete.

I see this note on Google search.

> counting all cycle in a graph is NP-Complete.

```
are these two sentence equivalences ? can we say these two is NP-Hard?
```

Thanks for every useful note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`are these two sentence equivalences ?`

Yes but it's not phrased properly. None of those questions are decision problems. Decision problems return either true or false. NP-Complete is a categorization of decision problems so it'll be "improper" to say the above are NP-Complete. But if we say, "Are there X number of cycles in a graph?" that would be a NP-Complete question.

`can we say these two is NP-Hard?`
Yes NP-Hard means it's as hard as NP at least so because these two problems are NP-Complete then this is true.

Comment: you means two of them is np-complete and np-hard? or it's better decision problem is np-hard or np-complete?

Comment: NP Complete problems are NP-Hard but NP-Hard problems may not be NP Complete.

Comment: you means "Finding of all cycle in a graph is NP-Complete." is np-hard with this phrase?

Comment: Finding all the cycles in a graph is not a decision problem so it's improper to categorize it as either NP-Hard or NP-Complete. But if it was Is there at least X cycles in a graph? That's NP-Complete and hence NP-Hard

Comment: can we say  "Finding of all cycle in a graph is not poly time solution."

Comment: Well it doesn't have a KNOWN polynomial time solution. If you claim that there's is no polynomial time solution then you must have proven P != NP in which case you wouldn't need my help haha.